# Retrieve all notifications from firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-notifications

I have set up push notifications in my app using firebase. My question is how do I retrieve all the notifications I have previously sent so I can display them in an iOS app. Is there a firebase API for this? I have looked through the firebase documents and don't see any API for retrieving notifications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no API for this, you can use Firebase Analytics however to log events when incoming messages are opened.